# Python sqlite3 update statment not updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

So I've got this sql (it's using (1,1,1) as I wanted to eliminate the possibility that it was taking the wrong argument for the OrderID (which is 1 in this case)), it's using the function which is displayed below. For some reason, it returns no error when run, but doesn't update the table even though it looks identical to sql elsewhere in my code that works fine.

The fields in my database are all set to text apart from the ID... I think that's everything, thanks in advance for your suggestions.

```
query("UPDATE Orders SET CustomerID = ?, OrderDate = ? WHERE OrderID = ?", (1, 1, 1))

def query(sql, data = None):
with sqlite3.connect("notDataBase1.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    if data == None:
        cursor.execute(sql)
    else:
        cursor.execute(sql, data)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return results
```

Comment: You never call `.commit()` to commit (save) your changes. Or is that called outside of the shown code somewhere?

Comment: Is a cursor supposed to return results with `fetchall()` after an `UPDATE` query? (I honestly don't know, I've only ever used it with SELECT. I don't see it specifically addressed in the documentation.)

Comment: It returns nothing if it's just SELECT.

Comment: @SirNibbleIII I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: I haven't got .commit(), I imagine you're now going to say that I need to put it in so I'll go try it

Comment: As in there's no error it just returns null, so it doesn't really matter if you fetchall

Comment: Just added 'db.commit' but it hasn't affected anything. I completely forgot about it as my other update statements worked without it for some reason.

Comment: In my testing, the update seems to be happening just fine. You don't get anything returned, but when I do a select after running it, I get the updated row as expected.

Comment: @glibdud Okay, so I'm assuming there's something wrong with my database? I'll delete it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like someone said in the comments, you need to run `db.commit()` after your query to write the transaction to the database. You can read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for more details. You also don't need to fetch for an `UPDATE` query. Something like this:

```
update("UPDATE Orders SET CustomerID = ?, OrderDate = ? WHERE OrderID = ?", (1, 1, 1))

def update(sql, data):
    with sqlite3.connect("notDataBase1.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, data)
        db.commit()
```

Comment: Just added it, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Also, do you definitely need this as I have updated things elsewhere in my code and they have worked just fine.

Comment: @SirNibbleIII If you just unindent your `return` one level so that it's outside the `with` block, the context should take care of doing the commit for you. (It might be doing it already... I'm not sure how contexts react if you return from within them.)

Comment: @SirNibbleIII In the docs I linked "commits transactions implicitly before a non-DML, non-query statement (i. e. anything other than SELECT or the aforementioned)". This means that if you don't commit, it'll commit for you on an update query. It's definitely good practice to commit after every update (or logical transaction) though.

Comment: I just realised I put my function for clearing out old orders that weren't confirmed in between making a blank order and confirming it so it got deleted before it could be updated... Thanks for the heads up about `db.commit` though!